# Semantic search on Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-synonyms

I love this website and I'd like it to be more powerful.

[Tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) are the closest concept to semantic search, but it's impossible to **search inside tag descriptions**.

For example, if you search in "Type to find tags" the keyword "reputation", you're not going to get the tags "voting", "bounty", "flair", etc. which are all relevant terms. It's like a search engine that only searches pages titles.

[Tag synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) are another semantic idea  but it would be better to create a **semantic network** that represents the relationships among keywords. An example is WordNet: http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn

Comment: Pekka: "simple substitutions?" Ask that question to Google who uses semantic search terms expansion. @gnat If I had your rep score I will also moderate your comments as "not constructive", but I can't with just 1 pt.

Comment: @gnat well, the substitution patterns would have to look different for Stack Overflow. (As said, this isn't really about *semantic* search, as far as I understand it.)

Comment: I agree "substitutions" is the wrong word but this is not about semanticity in the sense of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web